# How the map is serialized? (Java)

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I use Jackson (ObjectMapper) to serialize some objects to string (json representation). Object example:

```
{
  "name": "test_name",
  "test_map_key": {                     <---- Map<String, List<String>>
     "key_map": ["value1","value2"]   
  }
}
```

Json representation should be like above, but what I've got using **mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject)**

```
{
    "name": "test_name",
    "key_map": ["value1","value2"]
}
```

The 'test_map_key' is disappear and was taken internal key taken as a field. Is it possible to fix? Maybe someone paces this?

Comment: It is hard to say without the classes, but it seems like the class containing the `Map<String, List<String>>` is the one you need to look at.

Comment: Please add the class you are trying to serialize from

Comment: Please add the relevant code for the class you're serializing and how you've configured the ObjectMapper. On recreating your mentioned object (name + map of lists) i do get the expected output.